# FreeBSD process file location

Tags: freebsd

I have a PHP based script that stops two of the same process executing(via crontab), on CentOS I did the check for the running process via the following:

```
if(file_exists("/proc/{$pid}" )) {
```

However it seems that freeBSD does not support this same structure, is there a similar location I can check against? Or do I have to do a shell command?

Comment: 1. It is unclear how this check can prevent executing same process twice.
2. If you need lock to prevent two copies of same script running from cron more easy way is to use lockf(1) command. E. g. `lockf -t0 /path/to/cronjob.php` Exact options depends on your use case.

Comment: Anyway your can mount /proc on FreeBSD, see procfs(5). It very different from linux one, but /proc/PID entries probably can be used. But procfs considered obsolete and potentially unsecure feature (in this subsystem was discovered some vulnerabilities in the past, and now it rarely used and has little oversight).

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way of locking cron jobs (against parallel execution) is [lockf(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lockf&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) command. It available on FreeBSD and Mac OS X. Linux has very similar `flock` command (but options are different).

E. g.

`* * * * * lockf -st0 /tmp/foo.lock /path/to/foo-script`

If foo-script will be running more than one minute, next one will not be started. `-t0` mean don't wait for lock, just exit.

If desired it is possible to wait for lock, e, g,

`@hourly lockf -st1800 /tmp/foo.lock /path/to/foo-script`

will wait 30 minutes for lock and if lock still held, then exit.

If long running process is abnormal situation and indicates some error it is useful to send error message to admin:

`MAILTO=cron-mail@example.org
@daily lockf -t0 /tmp/foo.lock /path/to/foo-script`

(-s "silent" option is removed, because error message is need).